# Tippy.js does not keep position when content is zoomed

Tags: tooltip, zooming, tippyjs

I'm using Tippyjs for a simple tooltip on hover. It works fine when no zoom is set.

[image]

I'm using Chromium and when I set the browser zoom to 150% the tooltip gets displaced.

[image]

I haven't used Tippy before but I thought it would be fairly standard for a library like this to accommodate zoom.

I've tried searching on SO and looking at the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was remarkably simple: add `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the html page.

See: https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/faq/